# How to generate a 100x6 matrix with different values in each column in C++

Tags: c++

I'm a newbie programmer, almost zero experience with C++, in order to translate MATLAB code manually I need to generate a 100x6 matrix. According to what I investigated so far, I should use `std::vector` (vector of vectors). The problem is I don't know how to add values to the matrix in this way: 
100 rows, then each column should have these values:

```
column 1: sin(2*pi*0.05)
column 2: cos(2*pi*0.05)
column 3: sin(4*pi*0.05)
column 4: cos(4*pi*0.05)
column 5: sin(6*pi*0.05)
column 6: cos(6*pi*0.05)
```

I've only found very basic examples with std:vector and nested for loops which I fail to adapt to this particular problem. Can someone give me a hint of how to solve this problem?.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> matrix;
matrix.resize(100);
for (auto & line : matrix) {
    line.resize(6);
}
```

And then you can do:

```
matrix[x1][y1] = someValue;
otherValue = matrix[x2][y2];
```

etc.

But, if you know you will have a fixed size for your matrix, you can just do:

```
double matrix[100][6] = { 0.0 };
```

instead of creating the vectors.